# Creating copies of feature point geometries based on value in that feature's attributes using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to take a point feature and create copies of the geometries based on a value in the attribute table associated with that point.

Let's say you have 3 points; A, B and C.

- Point A has a value of 2
- Point B has a value of 5
- Point C has a value of 0

The output from my desired result would have 7 points total.

- 2 records of Point A
- 5 records of Point B
- 0 records of Point C

I'm working in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.

I have some experience in ArcPy as well if that would be a preferred approach.

Ideally I'd like to find a way to automate this; essentially selecting a feature and copying and pasting it by the number of times appropriate based on it's field value.

I have been thinking about utilizing search/update cursors, but not sure how efficient that would be.

For reference, there are about 32,000 points with a sum value of 76,000 in the desired field. So the final output should have 76,000 points.

Comment: So, while everyone out there tries to avoid duplicate geometries, you want to create them?

Comment: Erik - Precisely!

Comment: You could copy the feature class to a new one (where value > 0) then iteratively select for value > 1...MaxValue and execute an append from the original to the copy, but a cursor copy is going to be more conventional.

Comment: If you also seek answers using QGIS, ArcGIS Pro or Manifold then please ask them as new questions so that you can describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck with each.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can achieve that with a python-script, using a SearchCursor on your original feature class and an InsertCursor that iterates based on the value in the attribute field to write to a new feature class.

To illustrate the principle:

```
tab = [['A', 2], ['B', 5], ['C', 0]] # Insert SerachCursor here

for row in tab: 
    if row[1] > 0:
        for i in range(row[1]):
            print row[0] # Insert InsertCursor here
```

The output:

```
>>> 
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
>>>
```

Update: A quick-and-dirty script following the principles above (assuming here that row[1] is the attribute with the number of duplicates to crate):

```
import arcpy, os

GDB = 'mygdb.gdb'
fc_in = 'fc_input'
fc_out = 'fc_output'
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(os.sep.join([GDB, fc_in]))]

if arcpy.Exists(os.sep.join([GDB, fc_out])):
    arcpy.TruncateTable_management(os.sep.join([GDB, fc_out]))
else:
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(GDB, fc_out, arcpy.Describe(os.sep.join([GDB, fc_in])).shapeType, os.sep.join([GDB, fc_in]), spatial_reference=os.sep.join([GDB, fc_in]))
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.sep.join([GDB, fc_out]), fields) as cursor1:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.sep.join([GDB, fc_in]), fields) as cursor2:
        for row in cursor2:
            for i in range(row[1]):
                cursor1.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but didn't know if there were more efficient methods, or perhaps a tool I could just run that I didn't know about haha. I know people try to AVOID exactly what I'm doing, but I'm testing something for a statistical analysis using attribute based geometries rather than physical object geometries for a point density

Comment: There might be more efficient methods, but off the top of my head I can't think of any based on your available tools.